# ASP.NET Process.start won't run on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using process.start to execute schtasks.exe. The code that works on my development PC (Windows 10) won't work on an old Windows Server 2012 nor will it work on a Windows 2012 production server. I'm sure this is some kind of permissions problems but I've exhausted what to try. I've compared IIS settings and file manager permissions but just haven't identified anything different between Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 that would cause the code not to work on just the servers. The errors that we're seeing in the event log is that conhost.exe is faulting followed by the schtasks.exe faulting. The scheduled task is set to run with an Admin User with corresponding password.

Here is the code that works on Windows 10 but faults on Windows Server 2012.

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe",
        Arguments = "/run /tn NameOfExistingScheduledTask",
        UserName = "AdminUser",
        Password = securePass,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

if (!proc.Start())
{
    StreamReader myStreamReader = proc.StandardError;
    Console.WriteLine(myStreamReader.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be picky.

FWIW the way I would try is this.

1. Create a new service account for the server
2. Change your creds to the service account name and service account password
3. Press Windows button
4. search for Run
5. Run secpol.msc
6. Navigate to Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
7. Double click on Log on as batch job on right hand side
8. Add your service account

Comment: Thank you drzounds - I really appreciate that you took the time to help me. I gave up on trying to get this to work just today. Instead I'm writing an event to Windows event viewer. I'm using that event to trigger the start of my scheduled task. Kind of a kludge but I was beyond frustration.

I keep all of my non-working code in case I want to use it down the line. I'll keep your suggestion with the code. Hopefully the next person in my shoes will have your solution handy now.

Thanks again.